# How can I save an entire list of items true or false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm following Ryan Bates, [Railscast episode 52](http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes) and I've translated relevant parts of the code to work with Rails 3.0.0.beta2. In Ryan's case, he simply marks items incomplete and saves a timestamp. If an Item contains a timestamp the model returns the item in the completed list.

I'm attempting to save **ALL values true or false**, depending on whether the check_box_tag is selected or not (using boolean). I am able to save ONLY selected items, true or false. How can I save an entire list of items true or false, depending on whether the checkbox is selected? The following is my attempt:

controller logic:

```
 def yardsign
    Add.update_all(["yardsign=?", true], :id => params[:yard_ids])
    redirect_to adds_path
  end
```

html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag yardsign_adds_path, :method => :put do %>
<% @adds.each do |add| %>
  <td><%= check_box_tag "yard_ids[]", add.id %></td>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :adds do
    collection do
     put :yardsign 
  end
end
```

Terminal

```
Started POST "/adds/yardsign" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-04-15 19:22:49
  Processing by AddsController#yardsign as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update", "yardsigntakers"=>["1", "2"], "authenticity_token"=>"3arhsxg/Ky+0W7RNM2T3QditMTJmOnLR5CqmMYWN4Qw="}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.8ms)  UPDATE "adds" SET yardsign='t' WHERE ("adds"."id" IN (1, 2))
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/adds
```

Answer (score 0):

> The HTML specification says unchecked check boxes are not successful, and thus web browsers do not send them

You'll need to do something like the [check_box](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M001612) helper does and add a hidden input for unchecked items.